# Unable to get message from Eventlog "System" in Windows 2008 R2 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008

Could not able to get the message field while reading a windows event log using a powershell command. Is it a known issue in Windows 2008 Sp2 R2 or Is there any hotfix available in microsoft to resolve this issue. Below is the command which tried to get the event logs

PS C:\log_parsing> Get-WinEvent -LogName system -MaxEvents 3

```
TimeCreated         ProviderName                         Id Message 
-----------         ------------                         -- -------
24/04/2013 10:06... Microsoft-Window...                1006
24/04/2013 10:06... Microsoft-Window...                1006
24/04/2013 9:55:... Microsoft-Window...                1006
```

Regards

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181718/how-to-get-event-message-using-powershel

It appears that this is also a strange issue, possibly with PS3.

You can use the `Get-EventLog` command as a workaround.

See here on how to use it: [Get-EventLog command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176846.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your information.I tried with  get-eventlog -LogName System | ?{$_.eventid -eq 7036} | select message still i am getting an error saying like "The description for Event ID '1073748860' in Source 'Service Control Manager' cannot be found." Any idea

Comment: Thanks for your information.I tried with the below command get-eventlog -LogName System | ?{$_.eventid -eq 7036} | select message still i am getting an error saying like "The description for Event ID '1073748860' in Source 'Service Control Manager' cannot be found." Any idea <p>Regards</p>
<p>Karthik</p>